# linux module call functions which is in /proc/kallsyms but not exported

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have a project about linux kernel. We can't compile linux kernel and we have to call the not exported functions but this function can be found in /proc/kallsyms.(We can get the address of the function). But we don't know the specific method to call the function.
Would you please help us to solve the problem?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it is a function in the kernel itself and not a module all you have to do is:

```
int (funcp *)(int param1, int param2, ...) = FUNCTION_ADDRESS;

funcp(param1, param2, ...);
```

If it is a module things are a little bit more difficult since you need to record the offset of the function from the start of the kernel module load address, grab the load address from the kernel at runtime and compute the function address...

Comment: I have tries your method but has the error: called object ‘funcp’ is not a function.   I have done in the way you provide.  Would you please tell me why this error? Thank you very much.

Comment: It is my mistake, sorry. I didn't provide you with the correct syntax. I have edited my response and corrected it now.

Comment: Thank you very much. BTW, I have another question: in /proc/kallsyms we can get the address of function, but there is t or T type for the address. If the type is t, can we call the function through the way mentioned above?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. If the type is T btw, you don't need this trick because the function is exported

Comment: I guess the example you provided is also wrong. At least you cannot assign an address to this int (f*).